# Not enough bytes to read value of component 0 - Hector Composite column Read

Tags: cassandra, runtime-error, composite, hector

Facing an issue while reading from composite columns using hector api.

My column family:

```
create column family step_wise_stats_cc with key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type, UTF8Type)' and comparator = UTF8Type and default_validation_class = UTF8Type;
```

Data:
Row Key:{TYPE-1,SUB-TYPE-1}
Columns:Name1:Value1

I am querying it like this:

```
Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("cls1", "localhost:9160");;
Keyspace keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("ks1",cluster);;
Serializer se = StringSerializer.get();

Composite start = new Composite();
start.addComponent(0, "TYPE-1", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
start.addComponent(1, "SUB-TYPE-1", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
Composite end = new Composite();
end.addComponent(0, "TYPE-1", ComponentEquality.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);
start.addComponent(1, "SUB-TYPE-1", ComponentEquality.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);

SliceQuery<String, Composite, String> sliceQuery = HFactory.createSliceQuery(keyspace, se, CompositeSerializer.get(), se);;
sliceQuery.setColumnFamily("cf1");
sliceQuery.setKey("TYPE-1");
sliceQuery.setRange(start, start, false, 999);

QueryResult<ColumnSlice<Composite, String>> qr = sliceQuery.execute();
```

But getting below exception:
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestExc
eption(why:Not enough bytes to read value of component 0)

Any help?

Comment: You refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446187/astyanax-simple-write-throwing-this-exception-not-enough-bytes-to-read-value-o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row key is CompositeType, but you are setting the row key to "TYPE-1".  This is why Cassandra is giving you an error.

A slice query returns a range of columns for a given row.  You either need to specify a composite for your row key or change your data model by moving subtype to the column and make the column a composite.

Comment: I am a bit confused here over Composite row keys Vs Composite columns. Can you provide some good link on these?

Comment: The main difference is you can do range queries across columns but not rows.  So all queries need to know the full row key (whether a composite or not) but don't need to specify exact columns.

Comment: Thanks Richard, one more question. In my case, I have around 100 keys (or say TYPEs). Under each, there can be tens of thousands of SUB-TYPES. And each sub type will have 5-6 columns against it. How should I model my column family? Thanks in advance..